# Can not use "git pull" because of some error

Tags: github

git pull

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/neilyolol/aws.python.git/': error:0D0C50A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:unknown message digest algorithm

openssl version

OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014

python -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)'
OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
```

Comment: are you sure you dont want to `git clone`?

Comment: I already have pushed the code to git , later i modified them in my laptop (windows 7) and commited . Then I want to download the code to my linux server ...

Comment: "OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008" - that's pretty old. Updating your system might help.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue and I solved it by replacing the prefix of the url from https to git

Answer (score 4):

[GitHub seems to be using SHA256 as a hashing algorithm for SSL](https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fneilyolol%2Faws.python.git%2F), and that was not added to OpenSSL until [version 0.9.8o](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_library_init.html#NOTES).

I suspect (since you seem to be running 0.9.8e in Python which is pretty old) that your git is linked to/using a version of OpenSSL which is just plain too old.

Comment: @Neilyolol Update your server and see if that helps, otherwise you may need to compile a newer version of OpenSSL+git yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on an old CentOS machine, and was able to resolve it by upgrading openSSL. :)

```
sudo yum upgrade openssl
```