# Not Able to Git Push?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Made a new repository on [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.com) . Now I am trying to push a project folder to this repository. I can do `git add` & `git commit` but when I do `git push -u origin master` following error comes

`fatal: unable to access 'https://****@bitbucket.org/*****/***-2point0.git/': error:0D0C50A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:unknown message digest algorithm`

I re-installed `git` still same error. I found many other answers for this problem but still nothing is working.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a dupicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570689/can-not-use-git-pull-beacause-of-some-error).

It is probably a problem with the version of OpenSSL, at least this is what the error message is saying: the message digest algorithm used by Bitbucket is unknown to your host. 
Try to update OpenSSL to the latest version.

Otherwise, try setting the remote to use ssh rather than https:

```
git remote set-url --push origin git@bitbucket.org:*****/***-2point0.git
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[Can not use “git pull” beacause of some error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23571074/6309)", that could be linked to an old version of openssl.

Try to [upgrade your openssl version first](https://askubuntu.com/q/429385) ([even from sources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22952287/6309)).